# Do the commas in these aid readability?

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

If a unit of measurement represents a singular entity, is it permissible to use commas (as exampled in [1] in every pair below) to aid readability? Do you agree that the first example below in each pair is correct with the comma separators? I think that (1) in each set is the way to go.

(1) a two-hour, twenty-minute, forty-five-second marathon

(2) a two-hour twenty-minute  forty-five-second marathon

(3) a two-hour-twenty-minute-forty-five-second marathon

---

(1) a two-year, four-month, sixteen-day project

(2) a two-year four-month sixteen-day project

(3) a two-year-four-month-sixteen-day project

---

(1) a sixty-four-pound, eleven-and-a-half-ounce package

(2) a sixty-four-pound eleven-and-a-half-ounce package

(3) a sixty-four-pound-eleven-and-a-half-ounce package

---

(1) a seventy-five-foot, six-and-three-quarter-inch flagpole

(2) a seventy-five-foot six-and-three-quarter-inch flagpole

(3) a seventy-five-foot-six-and-three-quarter-inch flagpole

---

(1) a six-foot, ten-inch man

(2) a six-foot ten-inch man

(3) a six-foot-ten-inch man

---

(1) a nine-pound, seven-ounce baby

(2) a nine-pound seven-ounce baby

(3) a nine-pound-seven-ounce baby

Comment: To me, a 2h 20min 45s marathon is clearly the winner.

Answer (score 2):

It's a style issue, so there is no absolute rule to appeal to. But I agree with you that the commas are helpful additions. Here, rather than emphasizing natural pauses in speech, as they often do, the commas chiefly serve to help the reader's eye visually organize the numerical measurements into meaningful blocks, instead of appearing as an unrestrained (and formidable) mass.

Commas serve much the same purpose when used to punctuate very large numbers, as is done in standard U.S. and British English styles, though *Chicago Manual of Style*, 15th edition, notes that continental European (and SI) style (which uses a comma to represent the decimal point) uses letter spaces instead of commas to subdivide very large number into manageable triplets.

Comment: 'Here, rather than emphasizing natural pauses in speech, as they often do, the commas chiefly serve to help the reader's eye visually organize the numerical measurements [/data] into meaningful blocks instead of [recoil at the single formidable intimidating] mass.' **Please** find an authority (or even a style guide, or commentator other than yourself) endorsing this important usage.

Comment: The comma usage in large numbers sometimes did not correspond to a natural pause when reading. Yes, probably, in 294,675; No in 15,040.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: The issue of putting commas in extended exprssions of particular times comes up in CMOS 15th ed. 9.45, which provides these two translations in examples of "_Seconds and dates included_": "09:27:08.6 = 27 minutes, 8.6 seconds after 9:00 a.m." and "1999-05-10-16:09::41.3 = May 5, 1999, at 9 minutes, 41.3 seconds after 4:00 p.m." Similarly, the house style (not created by me) at the computer magazines where I worked specified using "X hours, Y minutes, Z seconds" and "X pounds, Y ounces" and "X feet, Y inches" for measurements.

Comment: On the other hand, AP style specifically rejects putting commas between parts of a multiunit measurement. I'll try to find that reference, too.

Comment: Thank you. I did ask. (I have a distinct aversion to CMOS. I'll cite your house style as an example!)

Comment: @Edwin: I misread the AP Stylebook item—it was banning commas between parts of a single spelled number (like three hundred fifty-three). But the _New York Times Manual of Style and Usage_ (1999) comes out four-square against Chicago, as these examples (from p. 107) indicate: "6 years 5 months 1 days old"; "8 pounds 3 ounces"; "7 feet 3 inches by 10 feet 5 inches (no commas)." I'll scout about and see whether any of the other style guides I have on hand address this (obviously divisive) style question.

Comment: The only other style guide I've found that addresses this specific question is _Words Into Type_ (all editions), which sides with the New York Times: "**Dimensions, weights, and measures.** Commas are unnecessary in the punctuation of phrases denoting dimensions, weights, and measures. [Examples:] five feet seven inches; His age is 6 years 4 months 12 days."